# Is there a way to differentiate validation and evaluation in AllenNLP?

Tags: allennlp

Sometimes we may want some minor different behaviors during validation (i.e, validation on dev set during training) and final evaluation. I am not sure whether there is a simple way to inform our model whether it's called by a `train` command or a `evaluate` command. Now what I can do is just to use `self.training` to distinguish them from training, but both validation and evaluation have `self.training == False`, which makes it not possible for me to distinguish them. I mean if it's my own pytorch framework, that's extremely easy to do, since I can write my own train and evaluate methods, but in AllenNLP they are both part of the framework code that I don't really want to modify. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: You could set a flag in the model to indicate that training is complete through an `EpochCallback`: https://docs.allennlp.org/v1.1.0/api/training/trainer/#epochcallback

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding your `Model`'s `from_archive()` method to set a flag, something like `self._training = False`.